# How to tune FastText parameter for OOV word?

Tags: parameters, word-embedding, fasttext, oov

I already heard that FastText is generating OOV word vectors using its n-gram's. It is already automatically built-in at FastText architecture or we should like to tune specific parameters to it? like an oov_tokens in Keras tokenizer. I already looking for what parameters to tune in Fast Text but I couldn't find any.

If anyone knows and wants to share their knowledge I would be very appreciative of that.

Thank you.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please accept it (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow).

Answer (score 1):

Vector generation for OOV words is integrated into fastText (at least in the original implementation by Facebook).

**To generate these vectors, fastText uses subword n-grams**. To learn more, you can read [this thread](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/475) and [this visual guide](https://amitness.com/2020/06/fasttext-embeddings/).

For this reason, the **parameters** that most influence the creation of vectors for OOV words are the following:

- `minn` (min length of char ngram)
- `maxn` (max length of char ngram)

For more information about fastText options/parameters, see [the official documentation](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/options.html).